# Upgrade Magento version to 2.1.4

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.1.3, magento-2.1.4

I need to upgrade Magento to the latest 2.1.4 version. But when I go to the "Web setup Wizard" and select "System Upgrade" I am getting following message:
You're already using the latest version, there's nothing for us to do.

See attached image for version info.

Can you tell me how I can upgrade magento version without using command line.
I upgraded magento to 2.1.3 from back-end.. maybe here are some old files (flag?) from previous update which tells that magento is up to date?

Please advise,
Sandra

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Update your magento version with the composer**.

Follow **below steps :**

1. On the command line **locate to magento root directory** and run below **commands in sequence.**
2. Then run this command - **composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.4 --no-update** (pass required update version number)
3. composer update
4. rm -rf var/di var/generation
5. php bin/magento cache:flush
6. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
7. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
8. php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**After that check your magento is updated**

Comment: Thanks @ManthanDave, but we would like to upgrade system from back-end. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then you need to do it manually

Comment: what do you mean manually?

Comment: Manually Meaning is `Download Magento 2.1.4` in your system then replace it with current version.